# How to declare viewcontroller globally

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

```
 let VC1 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loadingViewController") as! loadingViewController
```

How to declare VC1 globally so it can use it different function

Comment: Declare it in appDelegate, like var vc1: yourViewController!

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what you are trying to achieve?  You shouldn't need a global variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create it first like this (globally):

```
 var VC1 = LoadingViewController()
```

Then go to your view controller and add this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
VC1 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loadingViewController") as! loadingViewController
```

Comment: Thanks! It work! =)